# K018A DIY Kit 200V 500W Light-Dimmer Module - will it work w/ 120v or is modification required?

Tags: diy, kits

K018A DIY Kit 200V 500W Light-Dimmer Module - will it work w/ 120v 60Hz?  Or does it require modification to do so?

Bought this DIY Kit for further practice with my soldering iron, and also to tone down my stand-alone soldering iron of 60w (it doesn't have any circuitry).

You can find this DIY Kit on eBay cheap enough, and it gives a standard lighting dimmer circuit.  However, there are no instructions, and doesn't say where the input/output wires go.

All the components have been cataloged in a spreadsheet w/ reference to corresponding datasheets, as stated to always do on AfroTechMods - One of my favorite totorials on YouTube.  Also Colin's Lab with Colin Cunningham, & EEVBlog w/ Dave Jones are also favorites to watch and learn.

So, what do I do to Americanize this lighting dimming control module?  Or scrap it and buy another one?

Answer (score 1):

Is this it?

[image]

Here's another circuit with the same configuration but different component values. The main difference is the lower resistance of the control pot. Note that the power rating is lower on 120V because voltage is lower but maximum current is the same.

[image]

Your circuit should also work on lower voltage, but only part of the pot range will be useful. You could build it stock and note the pot position for minimum brightness, then measure the pot resistance at that position and replace it with the nearest equivalent.

Be careful - parts of this circuit have 120V on them and could kill you. Use a plastic knob, and put the board in an insulated box so no live metal parts can be touched!

Comment: Agreed. Finger-proof the pot threaded mount and nut too using a knob with a skirt on it or ground the case if it's metal.